# PHP dependency injection child class

Tags: php, dependency-injection, parent-child

let's say I have the following php classes: class user, class fileManager and class downloader extends fileManager

```
<?php
class user {
  private $name;
  public function __construct($name){
     $this->_name = $name;
  }
  public function getName(){
     return $this->_name;
  }
}
class fileManager {
  protected $user, $list;
  public function __construct($user, $list){
    $this->_user = $user;
    /* IF list is 1 OR 2... */
    $this->_list = $list
    /* for test: */
    echo $this->user->getName(); /* WORKS */
  }
  /* SOME METHODS */
}
class downloader extends fileManager {

  public function download($fileid){
    $this->_fileid = $fileid;
    /* if his username is set, he is logged in */
    if($this->user->getName()!=null){continue();}
  }
}

$user = new user('Jan');
echo $user->getName(); /* = jan */
$fm = new fileManager($user, 1);
$down = new downloader();
$down->download(1); 
/* FATAL ERROR, Call to a member function getName() on a non-object */
?>
```

So, jan is logged in, and opens the filemanager. The filemanager calls getName from the user class and knows thats it's jan. But if Jan wants to download file 1, the downloader doesn't recognize Jan. Why ? Aren't child classes supposed to inherit properties from parent classes?

Comment: You set `$_user` but address `$user`.

Comment: You don't seem to understand inheritance: downloader extends the __class__ filemanager, not a specific __instance__ of the filemanager class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$down is a new object. -> The constructor needs params.
Try

```
$user = new user('Jan');
echo $user->getName(); /* = jan */
$fm = new fileManager($user, 1);
$down = new downloader($user, 1);
$down->download(1);
```

Comment: You don't particularly even need `$fm = new fileManager($user, 1);`

Comment: i thought he may use it elsewhere

Comment: Thank you, I know it will work, but why can't the downloader class access the $user property from the fileManager class?

Comment: come on - lern about inheritance first

Comment: Yes, I need fileManager class, the code in the question is shrinked.

Comment: @user3156884 - Because the $user property isn't set in the filemanager __class__, it's set in a specific __instance__ of the filemanager class

Comment: As @Mark Baker wrote: you dont inherit an object - you inherit the class

Comment: Ow I see my error now, as you said, I inherit the class, not the object! Thanks guys! It's solved

Answer (score 0):

Not considering the typos, you have to pass values to the constructor when you instantiate the download class.

```
class user {
  private $name;
  public function __construct($name){
     $this->_name = $name;
  }
  public function getName(){
     return $this->_name;
  }
}
class fileManager {
  protected $user, $list;
  public function __construct($user, $list){
    $this->_user = $user;
    /* IF list is 1 OR 2... */
    $this->_list = $list;
    /* for test: */
    echo $this->_user->getName(); /* WORKS */
  }
  /* SOME METHODS */
}
class downloader extends fileManager {


  public function download($fileid){
    $this->_fileid = $fileid;
    /* if his username is set, he is logged in */
    if($this->_user->getName()==null)
        return false;

    //download file

  }
}

$user = new user('Jan');
echo $user->getName(); /* = jan */
$fm = new fileManager($user, 1);
$down = new downloader($user, 1);
$down->download(1);
```